# How can I propagate IIS settings across multiple servers in AD?

Tags: active-directory, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, automated-install

I have an active domain with about 20 machines, each running some applications we have setup.

We need to set up IIS on these machines to serve files that some of these applications are outputting.

In the server manager on the active directory system I installed IIS just fine across all of them, but I can't seem to find a way to set IIS settings from here (for example mime-types, virtual directories, etc...).

All of these instances of IIS need to be setup the exact same way.  Is there some way to set these settings up and propagate them to the rest of the machines in the active directory group?

Answer (score 2):

I have very little experience with IIS, but this looks like what you want:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264

This one is more recent:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129390(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at IIS Shared Configurations:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264